# How to set string value in button's tag

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7

I wanted to give a string value to UIButton tag for unique identities. but button tag do not understand string valve, it is replace into intger value.

Comment: you can use enums e.g.: typedef enum {
 kDrawing = 0,
 kPainting
} Posters; Then use it as button.tag = kDrawing;

Answer (score 1):

`UIView`'s `tag` property is of `NSInteger` type, so you can't place a string there. There are ways you can circumvent this, though (lookup tables, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The tag property is an int, and will not take a string.

However, you can create an enum, and then set the tags appropriately.

```
typedef enum : int {
    Tag1 = 1,
    Tag2
} MyTag;

...

view.tag = Tag1;
```

Comment: as stated in all of the answers, it simply cannot be done as such.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can subclass UIButton, and declare a NSString variable in the .h file.
`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tagString;`  You can then either set your buttons' class in Storyboards, or in code, and tag them with your strings by assigning that value.  Otherwise, use `typedef enum`.